# How do I stop <%= from html encoding my script tags?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to add js dynamically to my view using a custom HTML Helper. The problem I am facing is that the the following server tag is encoding my < and > to &lt and &gt.

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <%: Model.ProductName %>

    <%foreach (var script in Model.DynamicIncludes)
  {%>
      <%=Html.ScriptTag(Url.Content(script))%>
  <%} %>    

</asp:Content>
```

This is what my helper looks like:

```
 public static class ScriptHelper
    {
        public static string ScriptTag(this HtmlHelper helper, string path)
        {
            return string.Format("<script src='{0}' type='text/javascript'/>", path);
        }
    }
```

When I view the html source the script includes are being written to the reponse stream like so:

```
&lt;script src='../../Scripts/DataOutEventHandling.js' type='text/javascript'/&gt;
```

This application is written using the ASP.NET MVC 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the script tags were being nested. In my helper I added a closing  tag rather than using a self closing script tag and it fixed the problem.

```
 public static string ScriptTag(this HtmlHelper helper, string path)
    {
        return string.Format("<script src='{0}' type='text/javascript'></script>", path);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Html.Raw` around your formatted value.  You can place this anywhere you find approprate. e.g.

```
<%=Html.Raw(Html.ScriptTag(Url.Content(script)))%>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.raw(v=vs.99).aspx

Comment: In the helper? I have never used the raw() before.

Comment: Oh thanks.. but his is a MVC 2.0 application. I should have put that in my question to begin with. I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

`<%=Html.ScriptTag(Url.Content(script))%>` will not encode. You probably use  `<%:Html.ScriptTag(Url.Content(script))%>` which performs the HTML encoding.

Notice the difference between `<%=` and `<%:`.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm using the <%= That was my first assumption as well

Comment: @Nick, if you are using `<%=` and your helper method returns a `string`, **the result will not be HTML encoded**. I have tested it. You must be doing something else that you are not showing. As I like to say: works on my machine :-)

Comment: Ha.. one of my favorites as well!